React-Leaflet: Markers disappear when user navigate to other route
I use react-Leaflet to show hotels on map as a marker. It works when I have list of hotels(Hotels component) but when user click on a hotel (SingleHotel component) the markers disappear(have showed for less than 1 sec then disappear suddenly).
App Component:
function App() {
  return (
    <HotelsProvider>
      <div>
        <Toaster />
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LocationList />} />
          <Route path="/hotels" element={<AppLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<Hotels />} />
            <Route path=":id" element={<div>Single Hotel</div>} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </HotelsProvider>
  );
}

Hotels Component:
  return (
    <div className="searchList">
      <h2>Search Results{hotels.length}</h2>
      {hotels.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Link
            key={item.id}
            to={`/hotels/${item.id}?lat=${item.latitude}&lng=${item.longitude}`}
          >
            <div className="searchItem">
              <img src={item.medium_url} alt={item.name} />
              <div className="searchItemDesc">
                <p className="location">{item.smart_location}</p>
                <p className="name">{item.name}</p>
                <p className="price">
                  €&nbsp;{item.price}&nbsp;
                  <span>night</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );

Map component
function Map() {
  const { isLoading, hotels } = useHotels();
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState([32.4279, 53.688]);

  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const lat = searchParams.get("lat");
  const lng = searchParams.get("lng");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (lat && lng) {
      setMapCenter([lat, lng]);
    }
  }, [lat, lng]);
  return (
    <div className="mapContainer">
      <MapContainer
        className="map"
        center={mapCenter}
        zoom={6}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <ChangeCenter position={mapCenter} />
        {hotels.map((item) => (
          <Marker key={item.id} position={[item.latitude, item.longitude]}>
            <Popup>{item.host_location}</Popup>
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Map;

function ChangeCenter({ position }) {
  const map = useMap();
  map.setView(position);
  return null;
}


I create a layout that have two section on right hand it contains Map component and on left hand it contains Hotels component or SingleHotel component.
Sorry if I put all component I try to clear it.
